# Load license plate data from Excel

Tags: performance, python-3.x, excel, matrix

The code below gets data from an Excel spreadsheet and returns some values; this can take up to 15 minutes because the Excel has more than 15 columns and an average of 20,000 rows.

```py
def media_dia(data):
    lst_matric = []
    contaf = 0
    totinf = 0
    for x in range(1, mxrw1):
        date_time_str = ws_sheet1.cell(row=x, column=3).value
        if type(date_time_str) == str and len(date_time_str) > 9:
            date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            if date_time_obj.date() == data:
                lst_matric.append(ws_sheet1.cell(row=x, column=2).value)


    for m in lst_matric:
        gettem = 0
        contmed = 0

        for r in range(1, mxrw1):
            date_time_str = ws_sheet1.cell(row=r, column=3).value

            if type(date_time_str) == str and len(date_time_str) > 9:
                date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

                if date_time_obj.date() == data and ws_sheet1.cell(row=r, column=2).value == m:
                    if gettem == 0:
                        gettem = float(ws_sheet1.cell(row=r, column=10).value)
                    else:
                        gettem = float(gettem) + float(ws_sheet1.cell(row=r, column=10).value)
                    contmed += int(1)

        if (gettem / contmed) < 1:
            contaf += int(1)

        if gettem < 1:
            totinf += int(1)

    return {'totmedia<1h': "%i" % contaf, 'total<1h': totinf}
```

I'm using `openpyxl`.

`mxrw1` is the ws_sheet.max_row of the Excel file.

`data` is the date this function is called with a specific date and runs each time to get the data for a 7 days week.
`column=10` is the time a trip took.
`lst_matric` is the list with all the license plates in Excel.

This is the first row of the Excel file.

```
trip,license plate,
begin,end,na,na,na,na,km,hours,duration(h/min),na,na,na,na,na,na,na,na
 
MAQ.0024-20211114, VF-25-WJ, 2021-11-14 23:28:03, 2021-11-14 23:41:06,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0,65, 0,218, 0 h 13 min, 0, 26, 40,27, 20, 2,96, 0, Case
UNILOADER 1825B
```

How can i increase speed so it wont take 15 minutes to calculate?

```
    for m in lst_matric:
        gettem = 0
        contmed = 0

        for r in range(1, mxrw1):
            date_time_str = ws_sheet1.cell(row=r, column=3).value

            if type(date_time_str) == str and len(date_time_str) > 9 and ws_sheet1.cell(row=r, column=2).value == m:
                date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

                if date_time_obj.date() == data:
```

Comment: There are some missing information: the library you are using to read the excel file, the value of the variable `mxrw1` and, about the data, is there more than one record for the same license plate / date and time?

Comment: oh, ill add that in the post, as for your question, yes there are several records for value in collumn 10 for the same license plate and date

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am not available now, but I will help you later.

Comment: improved speed almost 80% but just adding and ws_sheet1.cell(row=r, column=2).value == m to the first if inside the for. made all the diference